# 2 Classes that share similar behaviours but unrelated.

Tags: design, object-oriented, php

I'm working on something at the moment and am a little confused.

I'm working on an enquiry system in PHP (it's Opencart Based, so MVC).

An enquiry comes in and depending on what form it was submitted from, depends on what folder it goes into to, folders pretty much mirror the categories, so an enquiry coming from TeeShirts for example would be in a folder called TeeShirts.
Folders aren't set up dynamically, they're manually set up by the admin.

I have something very similar at the moment, a Class for 'Status', the class can add/remove/modify status, tag status to enquiry, count status etc.

So.. The status class almost does exactly what I want the folder class to do, but the folder class is integral to the program, where as the enquiry class can be dropped, or replaced. The two things share lots similarities, enough so, that I'm thinking of creating a base class.

It's the fact that the folders are pretty much at the core of my application, I'm having second thoughts about tying them in together.

I'm looking for some advice just to get me started off, as I'm pretty new to programming, especially OOP, so ANY advice is welcome.

Comment: I find your question to be very confusing, but maybe I don't really understand the question. What exactly is the behavior of a Folder and of a Status? How are these similar?

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little unclear, but it sounds like you need to revisit your class design. My analysis is that you are selling **Product**s which belong to a **Category** and are stored in an **Inventory** (in your case a flat-file data store).

You will also need a **ProductStatus** class to hold stuff queried from the inventory e.g. Number in stock, isCurrentProduct() and perhaps details of variants (e.g. T shirt sizes).

Once you get the class hierarchy clean, code should automatically have one correct place to live. Some expectations:

- Inventory needs to know about products, but products should have no knowledge of how they are stored. If you are lucky, your store may expand and need a proper SQL database to hold the inventory. If you design it right, you only need to replace the inventory implementation. In Java I would enforce this by defining an IInventory interface, but I'm not sure what your options are in PHP - perhaps an Inventory abstract base class?.
- The ProductStatus class is likely to have almost no behavioural methods. Its job in life is to act as a data bucket transporting data beyween between the inventory and the GUI.
- The Folder class may exist inside your Inventory implementation, but should not leak out into the GUI, as it is an implementation detail.

Good luck - I hope this gives you something to think about.